# Transformar linhas da tabela em colunas com css

Tags: css, tabela-html, display

estou com uma dúvida/problema aqui. Gostaria de saber se podem me ajudar. Tenho uma tabela, composta de tbody, tr e td, mas gostaria de transformar as linhas em colunas, só que eu preciso que fique por exemplo 3 registros por linha vamos dizer, no terceiro, ele quebre e começa uma nova linha de registros, porque como posso ter 3, posso ter 12,15,8...e por ai. Aí vem a dúvida, eu consigo fazer isso com a propriedade display ?

O código da tabela é:

```
<th>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr>
</th>
<tr>
    <td>2</td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow em Português @DiegoAraujo . Poderia postar o código relevante juntamente com a sua pergunta?

Comment: O código da tabela é simples. <th><tr><td>1<td></tr><th><tr><td>2<td></tr> então quero transformar as linhas em colunas.